# Wrap words inside div with span (for example) tag, while the div has HTML tags inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to wrap each word with span tag inside paragraph. i successfully made it when there are no HTML tags inside the paragraph. But when the paragraph has HTML tags inside, it's going mess.

Here example when no HTML tags are inside the paragraph:

```js
$('div').html(function(i, v) { 
    return $.trim(v).replace(/(\w+)/g, '<i class="woord">$1</i>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    11111 22222 33333 44444
</div>
```

But when there are HTML tags inside the paragraph, it's going mess as following:

```js
$('div').html(function(i, v) { 
    return $.trim(v).replace(/(\w+)/g, '<i class="woord">$1</i>'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    11111 <span>22222 <small>33333</small></span> 44444
</div>
```

Thanks for **DrunkenPoney** for trying to implement that. He did the most, but it has broken the inside span content.

I want the result to be like this where every word appearing in the browser to be wrapped with `<i class="woord">` as following:

```
<div>
    <i>June</i> <span><i>10</i> <i>sssssss</i></span> <i>ggdgfdf</i>
</div>
```

His code result has broken the original `span` code structure as following:

```
<div>
  <i class="woord">11111</i> <i class="woord"><span>22222</span></i> <i class="woord"><small>33333</small></i> <i class="woord">44444</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that you need to traverse through all *text nodes*. In each text node, you can just replace all words with your desired string.
So it's quite clear about the idea. Note that searching/replacing using Regex against HTML tags is not recommended. That's why we need to deal with raw text nodes.

Also to help doing this conveniently using jQuery, we use the `replaceWith` method to in-place replace the text node with all returned from the Regex replacement.

Here is the detailed code:

```
var wrapHtml = function(textNode){
                 return $(textNode).replaceWith(
                                    textNode.nodeValue
                                            .replace(/\w+/g,"<i class='woord'>$&</i>"));
               };

$("div").contents().each(function(i,e){
 if(e.nodeType == 1){     
       var elems = [];
       elems.push(e);
       while(elems.length > 0){
         var ce = elems.pop();
         if(ce.nodeType == 1) {
          $(ce).contents().each(function(j,o){
              if(o.nodeType == 1) {
                   elems.push(o);
                  } else {
                   wrapHtml(o);
                  }
              });
         } else {
              wrapHtml(ce);
         }
       }     
     } else {
       wrapHtml(e);
     }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qq7t6a86/).

Comment: Fantastic dude! This is something neat and accurate. Thanks a lot :) Also there is something another came to my mind to complete this solid stuff you made. Assume i want to apply this idea to different HTML elements with different wrap replacements, then do i have to repeat this all code block and then change `div` and `<i>`, or there are some way to apply the idea without repeating the code block?

Comment: @MoradHamdy It depends on the complexitiy of your logic. If you just want to replace `<i>` with another element, you can add one more parameter to the function `wrapHtml` and replace the `<i></i>` there. However the input of `wrapHtml` is just `textNode`, so all it knows about is `textNode`, if you mean you need to apply different HTML wrapper (other than `<i>`) on different words contained in ***different elements*** - then you may need to check the parent element (containing the text node) to apply the corresponding tag accordingly. I think you can just modify code in `wrapHtml` function

Comment: I think that my comment was not clear. I mean to apply this code multiple times for different places like this: http://codepen.io/moradxd/pen/xqPyya You can see that i have duplicated the js code. Is there someway to implement this like plugin approach, such as passing containerSelector for example `.wrap-1`, wordTag for example `<i>`, wordClass for example `.word-1`, or someway you think will simplify repeating the js code. If this will be something complex for you, then no problem. I really thankful for what you already made so far :)

Comment: You just need to declare the function `wrapHtml` ***once***. Then you can declare another function (to actually traverse and replace) accepting one argument of jQuery collection, e.g: the signature of it could be `wrapWords(jNodes)`. In that function you can replace `$("div").contents()` (from the code in my answer) with `jNodes.contents()`. Then when using the function for different container elements, you can just call it, like this `wrapWords($("div"))`, `wrapWords($(".wrap-1"))`, ...

Comment: I did it here as you mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/L7m8ff9g/ Can we also do the same for the word container element and its class?